# Symfony 5 referencing a field within a referenced table

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

The question hard to formulate in just one sentence when I don't have the exact terms ready for use, but I'm basically working on a Symfony 5 project that involves a MySQL database. I use Twig to allow for communication between my PHP controllers and my HTML interface. Until now, I've been doing just fine using simple references to entity fields in Twig, such as:

```
myEntity.someField
```

To get the value I needed. However, I currently need to reference a "nested" field like so :

```
myEntity1.myEntity2Field.someField
```

The "nesting" making a world of a difference between the two. I am now getting an error when trying to do this (`Impossible to access an attribute ("someField") on a string variable ("<value from entity2 field>")`),
probably because my database is not organized correctly yet, from what I understand. Hopefully you could understand my difficulty. So, **how can I tweak my database to allow this sort of double-referencing to take place?**

**Note**: `myEntity2Field` refers to the name of a field from `Entity2` that should serve as a reference to the entire `Entity2` table, from which `someField` can then be extracted.

Comment: what is the error msg ?

Comment: @hous Right, I edited my original post to include that

Comment: Are you using Doctrine?  Have you setup a [relation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html) between entity1 and entity2?  In twig you would have something like: entity1.entity2.someEntity2Property which would transform to $entity1->getEntity2()->getSomeProperty().

Comment: @Cerad I am using Doctrine too indeed, but no relation between entity1 and 2 that I know of. I'll see if I can try what you are telling me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error you are getting is because you are trying to access a value from a string or integer, not an Object.

myEntity.someField is the same as $myEntity->getSomeField() if you have a getter Method or $myEntity->someField if you are accessing the property directly.

If someField value is not an Object you can only access the value but if its an Object you will be able to access the other object properties and methods in this way.

To do so the best way is to use association(relation) between your entities spically if you have the association already in the database and if you build your relations right in your database so you jaut have to refernce this relation or association between your entities and doctrine will do the rest for you.
as an example:

```
    <?php
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")
     * @JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $address;
}

/** @Entity */
class Address
{
    private $street;
    
    public function getStreet(){
     ....
    }

}
```

this example is a ManyToOne relation between the user and the addresse entity with the getters methos in the user entitiy you will be able to use the nesting when you access the user:

```
$user->getAddress()->getStreet()
```

as an example and this will work in twig also:

```
{{user.address.street}}
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional

the other way you can get the object inside your calss and map it with methods so you can access it as you want.

i hope i will be able to help you with this info.

Comment: Thank you, that mostly made it for me. What I mean is adding this ManyToOne relation made me able to build my program in the right direction, but since I'm not an expert in everything yet, I still got errors in the process that seemingly are not fatal. Moving along fine with my project thanks to this!